# ATL + '.' like shortcut to get previous command parameter

Tags: linux, bash, keyboard-shortcuts

I use <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> very frequently on bash. But some time I go one past the parameter I want . So I was looking for a way to call the next parameter from the history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like most Readline commands, `yank-last-arg` (the command bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>) can take a numeric argument. Type <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>, then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> to invoke the command with an argument of -1 (`-` by itself defaults to -1 if it isn't followed by an actual number). A negative number reverses the direction of the search for the "last" arg.